# Haskell stack and GHC.Paths.libdir

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am asking GHC for the lib path and it gives me a path that doesn't exist:

```
bash-3.2$ stack eval GHC.Paths.libdir
unknown option: 'c'
"/Users/alexey/haskell/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3"
```

This folder does not exist, not in my `PATH` and doesn't appear anywhere in my `env`. I don't currently have global/system GHC installed.

at the same time I get

```
bash-3.2$ stack exec ghc -- --print-libdir
/Users/alexey/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3
```

which is expected.

This is not project specific and is replicated in any project that uses GHC 7.10.3.

Both commands show the same and correct output when executed in other projects that use other GHC version (8.0.1).

Where this wrong path is coming from and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of stack are you using? I'm using 1.2.0 and the eval works.

Comment: And my configuration is similar to yours -- no globally installed GHC.

Comment: @scootermefecit I use stack 1.3, but think it is something in my configuration. I perhaps used to have a global GHC long ago, and it may even have been in this folder. So there might be some leftovers somewhere but I couldn't figure out what and where

Comment: It looks like the main difference between you and me is compiler version: I'm using 8.0.1. If I force 7.10.3, you're right, the stack command doesn't work.